# All Macros Run Extremely Slow After Workbook Buildout. Recommended trouble shooting procedure?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been building out an Excel workbook that is offered by Interactive Brokers for API trade Execution.  Over the last few years I've been adding sheets that include new automated trade strategies.

Now the workbook is at a point where Macros that take less than a second to run on previous versions of the modified workbook that I have been building out take 15 seconds or even longer.  I've spent a lot of time trying to find the source of the problem.

- I've deleted sheets
- I've deleted code from each sheet
- I've removed conditional formating, any and all Index, vlookup or like functions

I can not find the source of the problem.

If anyone has any suggestions on what else to try it would be greatly appreciated.

[If it's relevant the API sample excel file (which I've built out) van be found here](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=5041)

Comment: It would help to show a simplified example of the type of thing you’ve implemented. Are you maybe making multiple API calls in quick succession? Do you have some mechanism for caching api results which are unlikely to change, instead of re-calling the api over and over?  General advise about excel performance may not be your best approach if there’s something specific you can address

Comment: Instead of deleting sheets, have have you considered recreating the workbook (via copy-pasting values/formulas & formatting -- instead of moving the whole sheet)? If you do one sheet at a time and run any code relating to that sheet, you may be able to see which sheet is responsible (assuming a sheet is to blame). Before doing any of this, I would run the code on a different machine and attempt to replicate the slow behaviour there too.

Comment: I haven't modified the API functionality in the spreadsheet.  My VBA skills are not that advanced.  The Macros run fast when Auto Calculation is turned off and Manual Calcualtion is enabled.  They slow Macro speed is similar across all 6 of my computers with this workbook.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered similar situations in the past. Here is something you can try:

1. Open a **blank** Excel workbook
2. Click File > Open > **Browse** *(important - don't use the recent list)*
3. Locate and select/highlight your file in question, do NOT open yet
4. Click the drop-down arrow next to the `Open` button
5. Select `Open and Repair`

> **Keep in mind that repairing your workbook may result in losing some formatting. It's advised that you create a backup before proceeding.**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I tried the repair option and the repaired workbook shows no improvement in Macro speed unfortunately.  It was worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things you could try.

Try turning off Auto calc (even if the macros require it to be on) just to test to see if it is quicker now. If that fixes it then there is an issue with a formula somewhere.

If that doesn't work try dropping some
`Debug.print now ()` at regular intervals in the code on both the original and modified file, then compare the times in the immediate window to identify the piece of code slowing it down.

Anither thing if the file has increased in size more then expected you could try clearing excess formats. It's built into a free add-in called enquire found in excel. Just go to manage add-ons options and turn it on.

Comment: I've turned Calculation to Manual and the code runs very quickly as it should.  I now know that the problem is most likely in a formula and not the code or conditional formatting.  Any suggestions from here?  I may have to rebuild the entire workbook by copying over sheets and/or formulas one at a time.  I'm trying to avoid this because it will take an very large amount of time.  I hope I'm responding in the proper format for these forums.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Theres a few things to look for


Excel calcs left to right, up to down. So if you have a formula at the bottom of the page that impacts a formula at the top, the sheet will have to calc twice.


Make sure any formula with ranges in only reference relevant cells (not entire columns or large ranges)


Are you using custom functions as these can be slow.

You have already removed vlookups, but if you need them change them to index matches.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please check this article
   [Region Settings: Big Impact on Excel’s Calculation Speed](http://professor-excel.com/region-settings/)
2. You did not mention the workbook *size*, amount of RAM, etc.
   Try decreasing the size by saving the file as ".xlxb" (binary Excel file). It will not affect the macros functionality and the size of the file will be significantly reduced.
3. Also, check the external links, if any (Data menu -> Edit links) and investigate.